# Excel: making a list of data that starts with the same characters

Tags: excel-formula

I have a huge list of part numbers 12SWE-02423 for example, and I want to be able to input just the 12SWE part to a cell, and make a list of all of the full part numbers that start with the 12SWE so that I can put them in a drop-down menu.
Preferably so that I can just put the 12SWE into cell A1 and have the drop-down menu populate itself in A2.

Comment: You could use =left(A1,5) where A1 is you cell.

Comment: I'm thinking this will push you into macros. I'm not seeing VisualBasic as a tag, not sure of your experience level. Are you comfortable with using the autofilter? Are you comfortable with macros and visual basic?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do what you want, but there are some trade offs (see below)

1) make a new workbook. On Sheet 1 paste your product numbers into column 1.

2) in cell b1 write(no quotes) "`=left(a1,5)`" . Then populate rest of column (copy, select, paste  or  dobule click bottom right corner)

3) select columns A and B. Go to "Data"->"sort and filter"->"A-Z" (this is important)

4) select all of the data in column A. right click, then "Name a Range". Call it "PNS" (no quotes)

5) select all of the data in column B. right click, then "Name a Range". Call it "PNS_half" (no quotes)

6) in cell C1 write "12SNE" (or other test PN first part)

7) go to Formulas->defined names -> define name. In the name box put "list" (no quotes), and in the "refers to" box put (no quotes) :
`=OFFSET($B$2,MATCH($C$1,PNS_half,0)-1,0,COUNTIF(PNS_half,$C$1),1)`

8) select cell D1, go to "data"->"data validation". Select "list". In the "source" box write (no quotes) "`=list`". click ok.

The drop down in cell D1 will change as you write in cell C1.

In a similar fashion you could have a drop down of possible PN first-part(s) in C1, which once selected would in turn populate cell D1

```
        [A]             [B]         [C]         [D]
[1]     12SNE-02435     12SNE       12SWE       12SWE-02429(dropdown)
[2]     12SNE-02436     12SNE       
[3]     12SNE-02437     12SNE       
[4]     12SNE-02438     12SNE       
[5]     12SWB-02424     12SWB       
[6]     12SWB-02425     12SWB       
[7]     12SWB-02426     12SWB       
[8]     12SWE-02429     12SWE       
[9]     12SWE-02430     12SWE       
[10]    12SWE-02431     12SWE
```

Trade off-s :

- the product numbers list has to be in the same sheet as dropdown cell (data validation formula wont work otherwise) - but you can hide those columns
- the product numbers have to be sorted alphabetically (eg after additions)
- if a product number appears more than once it will also appear in a dropdown list more than once.
- once you change the text in cell C1, D1 won't update until the dropdown is opened and clicked
- if you want multiple dropdown boxes you will need to create a named range for each, and set a data validation list manually (or you could run a macro to do this in bulk)